# Is it necessary to renew thermal grease on Acer AO722?

Tags: cpu, temperature

Did anyone renewed the thermal grease on the Acer AO722, there is a need to renew it on this laptop? If yes how can I know for sure that I should to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you should "renew" your thermal paste is if your original paste has been removed or damaged (e.g. if you take off a fan for cleaning).

Once thermal paste is applied, it stays and doesn't go bad. If you notice that your temperatures go up, it's more likely that your air vents are blocked, that your fan isn't working properly. Try to clean it out with compressed air. If that doesn't work, try to disassemble the parts without taking off the heatsink from the CPU and clean it as much as possible.

Should you decide to replace the fan / heatsink, the new parts should come with cooling paste applied already, so again, no messing around with it.

I've been dealing with laptop / computer repairs for almost 2 decades and the times I actually needed cooling paste, I think I can count them on my two hands still.